# Bitwise not working

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I'm using bit wise for one of my scripts

```
<?php
$num1 = 33554432;
$num2 = 975827238;
if($num2 & $num1){
echo "Yes";
}else{
echo "No";
}
?>
```

The problem is that it echo's Yes when it should be no, any response would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

`33554432 & 975827238` is `33554432`, which is not zero, so no, it shouldn't be No.

```
  97582723810 = 1110100010100111110001001001102
&  3355443210 = 0000100000000000000000000000002
-----------------------------------------------
   3355443210 = 0000100000000000000000000000002
```